# In Jenkins, when creating a Windows build node, how is its "Path" assigned?

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins v2.375.1

I created a Windows build node and I did a "Launch agent via SSH" to launch it, and it's now online. When I go to its "System Information" page, I see a "Path" assigned to it. Where/how is it assigned? Better yet, how can I override it? I did set a "PATH" enironment variable in its Configuration page, but that value is NOT equal to the "Path" I see in the "System Information" page, shown below

[image]

Any clues? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in the node's `Configuration -> Launch method -> Advanced` section. See screen shot

[image]